Unable to export products in the admin
I'm not able to export products.
I go there:
System > Export > Products
I select CSV.
But below, I have no entity attributes I can select, so I can export anything.
I'm using M 2.4.7 p3, but had the same problem on M 2.4.1
If anyone has a clue ?
Many thanks

Is there any info message? The export process will use the queue. You need to run the command to execute the queues on your local.

Is any error while export ? if not then it will create export file by cron or you need to execute exportProcessor consumer queue via the ssh command.
